# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::LiveReload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm working on a **Rails 4.2** application on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I'm trying to run a rake task using the command below:

```
rake my-task
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::LiveReload

Trying to figure out how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue had to do with me not specifying the rails environment within which I wanted to run the rake command.

To specify the rails environment, I could use the `RAILS_ENV` variable this way:

```
rake my-task RAILS_ENV=production
```

OR if my environment is a **staging** environment:

```
rake my-task RAILS_ENV=staging
```

OR you could use the `export` command to pass the rails environment:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
rake my-task
```

OR if my environment is a **staging** environment:

```
export RAILS_ENV=staging
rake my-task
```

**Reference**: [websocket-server.rb and scheduler.rb Rack::LiveReload problem](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/1085#issuecomment-301607833)

That's all.